# C# AutoCAD Civil3D 2022 Activex get civil object properties

Tags: c#, alignment, autocad, autodesk, activexobject

I defined libraries in Civil 3D, but when I match the name with the object name, I get the error "No method or operation has been applied".
Can you help me?

```
AcadApplication ACAD = (AcadApplication)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application.24");
AcadDocument ADOC = ACAD.ActiveDocument;
AeccApplication CivilApp = ACAD.GetInterfaceObject("AeccXUiLand.AeccApplication.13.4");
AeccDocument AeccDoc = (AeccDocument)CivilApp.ActiveDocument;
            
AeccAlignmentsSiteless aliS = AeccDoc.AlignmentsSiteless;
           
AeccAlignment TAlignment;

object o1;
object o2;

AcadText AliName = null;
         
ADOC.Utility.GetEntity(out o1, out o2, "Select an alignment name on CAD");
AliName = (AcadText)o1;

// HERE THE PROBLEM!
foreach (AeccAlignment item in aliS)
{
    if (AliName.TextString == item.Name.ToString())
    {
        TAlignment = item;
                  
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried that in VB.net C# but i did'nt handle it :S